# Openvpn connected, but traffic still going through default router

Tags: arch-linux, openvpn

I've got a strange problem.
Everythings was working fine until my last update on archlinux.

I had my ufw firewall set for blocking everythings except tun0 and the default openvpn ip (for openvpn first connexion)! It was perfect, no leak if vpn down...

But after my update, nothing was going through openvpn. I tried resetting all config (network/openvpn/ufw) but nothing worked. I had to disable ufw for now, wich really bother me.

Openvpn says everything's fine, but my ip is still my default isp router.
It seems like all traffic is going through enp3s0 and not tun0

```
[root@user ~]# sudo systemctl status openvpn@Netherlands
● openvpn@Netherlands.service - OpenVPN connection to Netherlands
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service.d
       └─restart.conf
  Active: active (running) since dim. 2014-08-03 00:50:10 CEST; 8s ago
  Process: 7401 ExecStart=/usr/bin/openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf --daemon openvpn@%i --writepid /run/openvpn@%i.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Main PID: 7402 (openvpn)
  CGroup: /system.slice/system-openvpn.slice/openvpn@Netherlands.service
       └─7402 /usr/bin/openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/Netherlands.conf --daemon openvpn@Netherlands --writepid /run/openvpn@Netherlands.pid

août 03 00:50:10 user openvpn@Netherlands[7402]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
août 03 00:50:10 user openvpn@Netherlands[7402]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]109.xx.xx.xx:1194
août 03 00:50:10 user openvpn@Netherlands[7402]: WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
août 03 00:50:10 user openvpn@Netherlands[7402]: [VPN] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]109.xx.xx.xx:1194
août 03 00:50:12 user openvpn@Netherlands[7402]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
août 03 00:50:12 user openvpn@Netherlands[7402]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
août 03 00:50:12 user openvpn@Netherlands[7402]: /usr/bin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
août 03 00:50:12 user openvpn@Netherlands[7402]: /usr/bin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.192.1.6 peer 10.192.1.5
août 03 00:50:12 user openvpn@Netherlands[7402]: Initialization Sequence Completed

[root@user ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 enp3s0
10.192.1.1      10.192.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   20     0        0 tun0
10.192.1.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
109.xx.xx.xx    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp3s0
128.0.0.0       10.192.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    20     0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0

[root@user ~]# ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
    inet 192.168.1.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::12bf:48ff:fe7d:a5cc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 10:bf:48:7d:a5:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 13226  bytes 7955537 (7.5 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 12985  bytes 2539362 (2.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 8581  bytes 34060996 (32.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8581  bytes 34060996 (32.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.192.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.192.1.5
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 42  bytes 27761 (27.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 61  bytes 7072 (6.9 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0user
```

Comment: What is your test method for determining "nothing was going through openvpn"?

Comment: Checking my ip. I've got a conky script which check every 10s my ip and displays it. It looks like sometimes it's the vpn IP, but it never last long, and it gets back to my original isp ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally decided to reset my network settings:

1. uninstalled openvpn/dhclient/networkmanager/iptables/ufw (and all package related) with config removal
2. installed dhcpcd
3. rebooted
4. installed openvpn/iptables/ufw
5. rebootted

And everything's working fine again! :)